# Angular JS get value of date input with ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-model

I try to get the value of my input date html 5 component by binding it with ng-model like this:

```
<input type="date" id="dateFin" class="form-control" name="dateFin" ng-model="filtres.dateFin"
               placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy" min="01/01/2014"/>
```

And with the model :

```
$scope.filtres.dateFin = null;
```

I think the binding is correct because when I change the initial value to

```
$scope.filtres.dateFin = new Date();
```

The initial value is set to current date.

But my problem occurs when i try to get the value on my form processing. When debugging I saw that the value of `$scope.filtres.dateFin` become undefined when the value is changed. Should I override an onchange method or getting the value by another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, a little thanks your example I managed to find the issue. In fact I had a min-value and a format like `placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy" min="01/01/2014"` and this was preventing my code which was similar to yours to work.

I think the problem was the format of the min parameter with the good format everything is ok :

```
 min="2014-01-01"
```

My bad for removing for my code example on the question, I was juste trying to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/u2vkzemh/

html

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <input type="date" id="dateFin" name="dateFin" ng-model="filtres.dateFin"/>
    {{filtres.dateFin}}
    <button type="button" ng-click="show()">Show it</button>
    {{testDate}}
</div>
```

controller

```
function testCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.show=function(){
        $scope.testDate = $scope.filtres.dateFin;
    }
}
```

It seems to work well.